# Seeking a replacement for an Athlon II X2 240

Tags: processor

Current processor is:  **AMD Athlon II X2 240**

Current Motherboard is:  **DPJ Indonesia MP-A880GD23 V1.1**

I am looking for a CPU with around twice the benchmark potential. I will be reusing the same motherboard, so matching the CPU socket is essential.

In searching for a CPU, I have found what seems to be conflicting information which states that the CPU is an AM2+/AM3 CPU.

If there is more than one CPU available, please list them so I may choose which one I would prefer.

According to Belarc the memory module is

```
6144 Megabytes Usable Installed Memory

Slot 'DIMM0' is Empty
Slot 'DIMM1' is Empty
Slot 'DIMM2' has 2048 MB (serial number SerNum02)
Slot 'DIMM3' has 4096 MB (serial number SerNum03)
```

I have no idea whether the motherboard support AM2+ or AM3 port. I have o idea whether the memory is DDR3 or DDR2

The motherboard is so old it's not produced anymore.

My CPU-z says I am using AM3 slot

[image]

Comment: Jim if you are running DDR2 you have the AM2+ variant of the CPU, if you are running DDR3 you are running the AM3 variant of the CPU.  One cpu, TWO socket versions.  This is why you need to include more information in your posts than just a single piece of information.

Comment: Jim, I have suggested an edit to your question.  The fix will make the message more readable, as well as give us information needed to answer your question (after you fill in the section I left for you to fill in)

Comment: Please **[edit]** information about the type of RAM you currently have into your question.

Comment: I have no idea what the memory is.

Comment: How can the same CPU support 2 kind of socket anyway?

Comment: Jim, you have not been paying attention.  There are apparently two versions of the Athlon II X2 240.  One version is for the AM2+ while the other is for the AM3.    As for the type of RAM you have, can you take a DIMM out, and enter in any information that may be on a sticker on either side of the DIMM?.  Failing that, can you run a system diagnostics tool such as [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy)? This will tell you what type of ram you have, among other things.

Comment: Looks like it's clearly written socket AM3. I will send another memory information. I am using CPU-z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to add something to the answer.

There is confusion whether I am using AM2+ socket or AM3 sockets. Until today I still have a hard time believing that the same CPU with same product code have 2 versions.

This is very confusing. Hence, we can't know the socket just from the CPU code, which is currently Athlon II X2 240.

And this is where my main problem is.

Well if we want to know, the way is to use a software called CPU-z. From that software I easily find out that my mobo uses AM3 socket with DDR 3 memory.

[image]

[image]

Once I know the socket, finding the right CPU is easy.

Just go to https://www.cpubenchmark.net/socketType.html#id11 and there are lists of CPU

AMD II Phenom X6 is one of the thing that fit as NZKshatriya said.

Another I would like to add is that the CPU doesn't have several version. That one CPU simply fit on several sockets.

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3365776/cpu-socket-versions.html#19455769

Still not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find one, I would suggest going with an AMD Phenom II X6 1100T

I have a system running this chip, running as a server currently.  Nothing but smooth sailing when I was using it as a gaming/overclocking testbed.